# Examples of Magic Cards that use rule 115.2c

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What are some examples of cards in Magic the Gather that use the rule 115.2c?

> 115.2c Some effects allow a player to take an action at a later time, usually to end a continuous effect or to stop a delayed triggered
>   ability from triggering. Doing so is a special action. A player can
>   take such an action any time they have priority, unless that effect
>   specifies another timing restriction, for as long as the effect allows
>   it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An example of this (very rare) special action would be paying {U} to prevent the delayed trigger from [Quenchable Fire](https://scryfall.com/card/con/70/quenchable-fire).

> Quenchable Fire {3}{R}
>
> Sorcery
>
> Quenchable Fire deals 3 damage to target player or planeswalker. It deals an additional 3 damage to that player or planeswalker at the beginning of your next upkeep step unless that player or that planeswalker’s controller pays {U} before that step.

There are [three other cards](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3Aunless+o%3Abefore) with a similar template that also use 115.2c: [Glass Asp](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGlass%20Asp%5d), [Nafs Asp](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNafs%20Asp%5d), and [Sabertooth Cobra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSabertooth%20Cobra%5d).

The [Licids](https://scryfall.com/search?q=licid) from Tempest block also use 115.2c to enable you to end a continuous effect:

> Calming Licid {2}{W}
>
> Creature — Licid
>
> {W}, {T}: Calming Licid loses this ability and becomes an Aura enchantment with enchant creature. Attach it to target creature. You may pay {W} to end this effect.
>
> Enchanted creature can’t attack.